# how to scan very long document with scan snap

Tags: linux, debian, scanner, paper, xsane

I have a Fujitsu ScanSnap ix500. I want to scan a document (sales slip) that is overly long (about 50cm) but quite narrow.

So, I hoped the scanner would just pull it through and give me the whole image as one. Alternatively it would have been fine to give me the document as multiple scans and I would have to stitch it together then.

But when I attempt to scan it pulls in half the document and then aborts with an error message: "Dokumenteinzug blockiert" which translates to "document tray blocked". The scanner won't do anything until I open the tray and remove the document.

I use a Debian Linux and have the packages

```
ii  xsane                                    0.999-2                             amd64        featureful graphical frontend for SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy)
ii  xsane-common                             0.999-2                             all          xsane architecture independent files
```

Comment: Is cutting it into shorter pieces an option?

Comment: @DavidPostill No. The document needs to be in one piece. I can't fold it either because its a multi document scanner so it will un-fold it automatically and only pull in one side.

Comment: @DavidPostill I need to restate my previous comment: cutting is not functioning, but I found a way where folding works. See my answer.

Comment: I wonder what the scanner manual says about it. Also, did you try asking Fujitsu? It's clearly a very useful option and exactly the one I would expect this scanner to be suitable for.

Comment: @texnic Scanner manual didn't cover it. I did not try asking Fujitsu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Carrier Sheet that gets shipped with the Scan Snap.
Then you can fold the long slip as often as needed and make several scans after the other.

After that use a graphical program to stitch the images together. Not the most convenient solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

"Scanning a Page Longer than 14 Inches Using Your iX500:"

http://scansnapcommunity.com/tips-tricks/9501-scanning-a-page-longer-than-14-inches-using-your-ix500/

If you need further assistance then please contact the Fujitsu Technical Assistance Center.(800) 626-4686

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thank you for you contribution, but whilst this may potentially answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential information here, and provide the link for reference. Please **edit your answer** to include that information. Thanks :)

Comment: A national number is of no use in an international context (like Superuser). Please do include the information here in the answer, Links go stale far to fast.

Comment: So, this took about three years... Now the link is stale.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Keith! While it is no longer live, the Wayback Machine had a copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20131001153320/http://scansnapcommunity.com/tips-tricks/9501-scanning-a-page-longer-than-14-inches-using-your-ix500/ . The gist is to select any Image Quality other than "Excellent" under the ScanSnap Manager's "Scanning" tab, load your document, press and hold the blue Scan button on the iX500 for about 3 seconds until it flashes, then release it. Worked like a charm in ScanSnap Manager 7.2 L70.