# Scan documents longer than 14 inches with Brother scanner using SANE in Linux?

Tags: printer, scanner, brother-printer, xsane, sane

I have a Brother MFC-L3750CDW. I would like to scan documents longer than 14 inches (long receipts) from the feeder. I have found [many](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=ca&lang=en&prod=ads2500w_us&faqid=faq00003064_000) [articles](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/66963/%7E/how-do-i-scan-a-document-longer-than-legal-size-%288.5-x-14%29%3F) [on Brother's website](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=ds620_all&faqid=faq00100159_000) for how to do this with windows drivers, but not surprisingly they don't give Linux instructions. These all suggest to disable "auto deskew" and some other features to enable scanning beyond the normal maximum.

I have checked the options reported by my printer through [SANE](http://www.sane-project.org), and I don't see any option for this. I can set `br_y`, but it has a maximum of 355 mm (14 inches). Setting a value above this has no effect. [I found this in a mailing list](https://alioth-lists.debian.net/pipermail/sane-devel/2015-January/033003.html), but `scanimage --ald` doesn't seem to exist any longer. Here is [the list of options reported by my scanner](https://gist.github.com/MarcelRobitaille/088410131e8fd7ba5077bd493aaaf850) according to `python-sane`.

I found [this related issue on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/988257/how-to-scan-very-long-document-with-scan-snap), but it's for a Fujitsu scanner. The solution given was to fold the receipt, but I don't want to do that. I want it to be as straight as possible because I am doing OCR.

Is there any way to enable this?

Here is the code I am using to scan the document:

```
import sane
sane.init()
dev = sane.open('airscan:e1:Brother MFC-L3750CDW series')
dev.source = 'ADF'
dev.br_y = 5000
print(dev.opt)
dev.start()
im = dev.snap()
im.save(filename)
```

Using `scanimage` from the command line, I am unable to force the scanner to use the feeder and not the flatbed.

```
scanimage --mode Color --device-name "airscan:e0:Brother MFC-L3750CDW series" --buffer-size="10MB" -y 355mm --resolution 150dpi --batch="test_crop_desk_%d" -l 43 --batch-start 0 --format=tiff
```

Which specifies both `--device-name` and `--batch`.
It is still using the flatbed.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112350/scanner-assumes-document-feeder-is-legal-sized) help?

Comment: harrymc thanks for your comment. This is not working for me though. It is trying to scan from the flatbed, I can't force it to use the feeder.

Comment: [scanimage man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scanimage) describes the `batch*` parameters. See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383568/multiple-page-scan-using-scanimage) for examples. The command also has a `--device-name` parameter you might be able to use, see [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746126/scanimage-only-recognizes-scanner-as-adf-suddenly).

Comment: I am using `scanimage --mode Color --device-name "airscan:e0:Brother MFC-L3750CDW series" --buffer-size="10MB" -y 355mm --resolution 150dpi --batch="test_crop_desk_%d" -l 43 --batch-start 0 --format=tiff`, which specifies both `--device-name` and `--batch`. It is still using the flatbed. The Python code I added to my question is using the feeder, but limited to 14 inches.

Comment: Try to add `--source ADF` to the command.

Comment: The length of the scanned document is still only 14 inches with `--source ADF`

Comment: But does `--source ADF` force it to use the feeder?

Comment: Yes, `--source ADF` forces it to use the feeder

Comment: If it works, you should use as much as possible the command from my [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112350/scanner-assumes-document-feeder-is-legal-sized) with the addition of only `--source ADF`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134856/discussion-between-marcel-and-harrymc).

Comment: @Marcel were you able to find a solution? I'm running into the same issue with a Brother DS-640, and I get a 404 on your chat link.

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley No, never found a solution. I ended up setting up a system involving taking a picture on my phone: https://github.com/MarcelRobitaille/Receipt-Ingestion

Comment: @Marcel sorry to hear it, but that trick of using a QR code to find and transform the receipt is very clever! I ended up creating two automated workflows in the Brother iPrint & Scan app, used someone's Python function to deskew the ones >14in, used ocr.space's API, and was able to capture all the data cleanly/reliably. It works pretty well for me, I will link the writeup here when it's finished, in case other readers find it helpful.